# Failed to load resource: unsupported url

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, backbone.js, camera

My code throws this error `Failed to load resource: unsupported url` on the following line:

```
self.$el.find('.capturedImage').attr('src', imageData);
```

This is the value of `imageData`:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473&ext=JPG
```

This is happening when running a cordova app on the iPhone simulator using the plugin `cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"` Deployment Target in Xcode is set to 9.0

```
render: function (context, template) {
        var self = this;
        View.__super__.render.apply(this, [context, template]);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var imageData = app.selectedYoungPerson.imageData;
            if (app.selectedYoungPerson.fromCamera) {
                if (imageData.indexOf('data:image/jpeg;base64,') != 0 && imageData.indexOf('data:;base64,') != 0) {
                    self.$el.find('.capturedImage').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
                }
            }else{
                    self.$el.find('.capturedImage').attr('src', imageData);
            }
            self.startCrop.apply(self,[]);
        }, 1000);

getBrowseImage: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var destinationType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i)) ? navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL : navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI;
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imgData) {
                var fileName = 'img_'+(new Date()).valueOf()+'.jpg';
                if(data.callback) {
                    data.imgData = imgData;
                    data.fileName = fileName;
                    data.fromCamera = false;
                    data.callback.apply(data.ref, [data]);
                    //self.uploadImage(data);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                alert('Image cpature failed : '+err);
            }, {
                quality: 100,
                allowEdit: true,
                correctOrientation: true,
                destinationType: destinationType,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
        );
    },
```

This is my list of plugins:

cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-file 4.3.2 "File"

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.2 "File Transfer"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"

org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.11 "Console"

Comment: `assets-library` is a hosted application or just a folder?

Comment: It's just a folder

Comment: Then why the `://` in `assets-library://` ..?

Comment: It is just assigned like that

Comment: Assigned by whom? You are getting the error `unsupported url` so you should know whether you have a valid url or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this problem by replacing `navigator.camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI;` with `navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`

Comment: I have already used this NATIVE_URI but getting the same image view issue.

Comment: Use `FILE_URI` instead